# Backpropagation: How to derive gradient of final output with respect to cross entropy loss?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to train a simple neural net but I'm unsure of the correct backprop value to use.

I'm using a 2 layer NN (1 input, 1 hidden and 1 output layer), using ReLU activations. Here is my h2

```
h1 = np.maximum(0, X.dot(W1) + b1.T)
h2 = h1.dot(W2) + b2.T
score = h2
```

In this case, if I were to backprop my score with respect to the loss function (cross entropy loss), what should be the correct computation I should use?

Comment: i’m not sure if this is a programming question…try the [scicomp](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange. We can’t help you if we have no idea what you are talking about, or exactly what your *coding* problem is.

Comment: the short answer is "no", it is not 1 (nor even usualy). However it is a bit hard for me to follow your logic, could you rephrase your question? Are you asking if dL/dy = 1 usually? or dL/dw_y=1 (where w_y are weights in the output layer)? Neither of these is true.

Comment: Yes you're right. If dL/dy isn't 1, then how do I compute it, especially in this case if the loss is a cross entropy one?